# Method returning before result of AlertDialog box

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've a problem where I have a method that i call called processInfo(). This method essentially processes information collected from an NFC tag or QR code and writes it to the DB.
Depending on certain situations the processInfo method handles how the info is written to the DB. The processInfo method returns a boolean which if set to true, the info in the DB is then sent to a web server.

I have some logic within processInfo that says if condition A then write to DB and return true. this in turn sends it to the wewbservice. If condition B then show an Alertdialog box.
The Alertdialog box has an OK and CANCEL button. if ok is pressed then do what happens in condition A, if CANCEL is pressed then dissmiss the dialog and return false.

What is happening is if condition B happens the dialog is shown as expected, but it is returning to the calling method before any of the buttons are pressed. How can i make the app hang until at least one of the buttons are pressed?

I've tried using `while(! alertDialog.isShowing == true) -> return boolean`. But it drops out after `alertDialog.show()` and return to calling method.

```
success = false;

if(condition A) {
    // write to DB and return to caller
    return success = true;
} else {
    success = false;

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NfcscannerActivity.this);
    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please logout after ");
     // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click Ok to return to the menu")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            success = true;
        // write to DB                                          
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // if this button is clicked, just close
            // the dialog box and do nothing
            success = false;
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}

return success;
}
```

Comment: @Nitish Hi, unfortunately i tried that before but i'm using an anonymous inner class DialogInterface.onClickListener and overriding its onClick which has a return type of void. So you can't return a boolean

Comment: ya realized my mistake that's why I deleted my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@turtleboy  this is a simple example

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

```
    static final String TAG="TestActivity";

    static final int MSG_SEND_INFO_TO_SERVER = 1;

    static final int MSG_INFO_NOT_SEND_TO_SERVER = 2;

    boolean condition=false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i(TAG, "0000000000000000");
        your_methode();

    }

    Handler communication_handler =new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

            case MSG_SEND_INFO_TO_SERVER: 
                //send info to the web server
                Log.i(TAG, "11111111111111111");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "send msg to the server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case MSG_INFO_NOT_SEND_TO_SERVER: 
                //send info to the web server
                Log.i(TAG, "222222222222222222");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no msg to send to the server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;  
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void your_methode()
    {
        if(condition) {
            // write to DB
            communication_handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null,MSG_INFO_NOT_SEND_TO_SERVER,0));
            return ;
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please logout after ");
            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click Ok to return to the menu").setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // write to DB
                    // send msg 
                    communication_handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null,MSG_SEND_INFO_TO_SERVER,0));                                       
                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();

                    communication_handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null,MSG_INFO_NOT_SEND_TO_SERVER,0));

                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a callback method. Let's say `onResultObtained(boolean result)`:

```
boolean onResultObtained(boolean result) {
    if(result) {
         //write to DB and return to caller
         return true; 
    } else {
       return false; 
    }
}
```

**Actual code**

```
if(condition A){

   onResultChanged(true);

}else{
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                NfcscannerActivity.this);

                            // set title
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please logout after ");

                            // set dialog message
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Click Ok to return to the menu")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                               onResultChanged(true);


                                    }
                                  })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing

                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        onResultChanged(false);   
                                    }
                                });

                                alertDialogBuilder.show();


}
}
```

Another way to do this, is make variable success as global.

```
boolean success;
```

**processInfo()**

```
private void processInfo() {
    if (condition A) {
        success = true;
        //Save data to DB
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please logout after ");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click Ok to return to the menu")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                success = true;
                                //Save data to DB
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                success = false;
                            }
                        });

        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }
}
```

And, in your calling()

```
private void callingMethod(){
    if(success){
        //do your stuff
    } else {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @turtleboy what didn't work about it? if you want help you are going to have a be a bit more specific,

Comment: @FoamyGuy Hi, it didn't work because the program carries on executing once the dialog box appears. The dialog box is created inside a method called processInfo(). This method returns a boolean. The part of the app that calls processInfo tests whether true or false is returned then acts accordingly. So if true is returned then the data in DB is sent to webservice. With this code it returning before the user can click the ok/cancel key. so the web service is never called. hope that helps. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no blocking UI model in Android, everything is asynchronous.You must change the behavior. 
You can call the alertDialog in a thread or asyncTast or a looperThread
and if the info in the DB must be sent to a web server then send a msg to the principal thread (use Handler) and in handleMessage(Message msg) send the info.

Comment: Hi could you expand a little with a simplified example?